# How can I make grub changes permanent?

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, grub, manjaro

I removed a drive a few weeks ago and as part of the process I freed up a number of partitions on my OS drive. Whenever my machine starts I'm taken to the grub recovery. I am able to make it into my system by running the following commands:

```
set root=(hd3,1)
set prefix=(hd3,1)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

What I'd like to know is how and where I can make these changes permanent once I'm  booted into the OS?

EDIT:
update-grub did appear to do the trick on Manjaro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: `update-grub` is a Debianism and might not exist in Manjaro. Try `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` or `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` instead. If that does not help, check the file `/etc/default/grub` and files `/etc/grub.d/*_custom`.